# PHP Contact form submitting but not receiving

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I've got a contact form on my website, however whenever I click submit I do not receive anything to my e-mail address although it does say it has been submitted.

The HTML is as follows

```
<div id="contactform">
    <form name="contact" method="post" action="PHP/send_form_email.php">
    <ol>
        <li><label>To </label>
            <select name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">General Queries</option>
        <option value="2">Webmaster Queries</option>
        </select>
        </li>
    <li><label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input>
        </li>
    <li><label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
        </li>
    <li><label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"></input>
        </li>
    <li><label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
        </li>
    <li>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></input>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the PHP is

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
        $emailaddress[1] = "email1@email.com";
    $emailaddress[2] = "email2@email.com";
    $contactnameindex = $_REQUEST['emailaddress'];
    if ($contactnameindex == 0 || !isset($_REQUEST['emailaddress']))
            die ("You did not         choose a recipient. Please hit your browser back button and try again.");
    else
            $emailaddress = $emailaddress[$contactnameindex];

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if  (!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you  submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($message) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Message you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

Obviously the e-mail addresses I have used are not email1 and email2, but I have checked the actual addresses I have used and they are both typed correctly, can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try checking `print_r( $_POST );` value?

Comment: check using `if(mail())` that it send mail or not

Comment: supressing mail error with @mail is bad thing.

Comment: I believe Bojan means that the @ in front of the mail function call is suppressing errors, and you should remove it to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I've tried changing the @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); to @mail($emailaddress, clean_string($subject), $email_message, $headers); But it did not help, I then removed the @ symbol from the front of this but again it has not appeared to have changed anything. Unfortunately I am very new to PHP, although I have done CSS and HTML before, this is something completely new to me so I am at a bit of a loss as to where else in the coding to look.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$email_to` and `$email_subject` in your `mail()` are undefined.

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

your `$email_to` should probably be `$emailaddress`, based off

```
else $emailaddress = $emailaddress[$contactnameindex];
```

and your `$email_subject` should probably be `clean_string($subject)`, based off

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
```

so something like -

```
@mail($emailaddress, clean_string($subject), $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: I've tried changing the
     @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
to
     @mail($emailaddress, clean_string($subject), $email_message, $headers);

But it did not help, I then removed the @ symbol from the front of this as another comment suggested but again it has not appeared to have changed anything.

Unfortunately I am very new to PHP, although I have done CSS and HTML before, this is something completely new to me so I am at a bit of a loss as to where else in the coding to look.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    require_once "../common/lib.config.php";
    require_once "../classess/class.GymFacility.php";

    $Fobj= new GymFacility();

    if(!$_GET['iDisplayStart'])
        $StartIndex = 0;
    else
        $StartIndex = $_GET['iDisplayStart'];

    if(!$_GET['iDisplayLength'])
        $Limit = 10;
    else
        $Limit = $_GET['iDisplayLength']; 

    $result=$Fobj->GetAllGymFacility();

    $row=array();
    $link="";

    for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
    {   
        $link="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a id='addv' href=javascript:loadpg('gym_facility_v0/form_facility.php?id=".$result[$i]['refid']."')> <img src='../images/icons/middlenav/create.png' class='listimg' title='Edit '></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='addv' href=javascript:deleteitem('gym_facility_v0/delete_facility.php?id=".$result[$i]['refid']."')> <img src='../images/icons/middlenav/close.png' class='listimg' title='delete '></a> ";
        $row[]=array($i+1,$result[$i]['gymfacilities'],$link);

    }

    $totacnt=count($result);
    $fltcnt=count($result);

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $totacnt,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" =>$fltcnt ,
        "aaData" => $row);

    echo json_encode($output);

?>

<?php 
    require_once "../common/lib.config.php";
    require_once "../classess/class.GymFacility.php";

    $F=new GymFacility();

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $IpArr['stat']='R';
    $result=$F->DeleteGymFacility($IpArr,$id);
    echo "gym_facility_v0/facility.php";

?>





<?php
    require_once "../common/lib.config.php";
    require_once "../classess/class.QueryBuilder.php";

    class GymFacility extends QueryBuilder
    {
        public function GymFacility()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function AddGymFacility($IpArr)
        {           
            if(!$this->IsExist($IpArr['gymfacilities'],$refid=0)){
            $this->SetTable('gymfacility');
            $this->AddFlds($IpArr);
            return $this->AddQuery();
            }
            return 'E';

        }

        public function EditGymFacility($IpArr, $Refid)
        {
            if(!$this->IsExist($IpArr['gymfacilities'],$Refid)){
            $this->SetTable('gymfacility');
            $this->AddFlds($IpArr);
            $this->SetWhere("refid = '{$Refid}'");
            $this->UpdQuery();
            return $Refid;
            }
            return 'E';
        }

        public function UpdateGymFacility($IpArr, $Refid)
        {
                $this->SetTable('gymfacility');
                $this->AddFlds($IpArr);
                $this->SetWhere("refid = '{$Refid}'");
                $this->UpdQuery();
                return $Refid;
        }

        public function DeleteGymFacility($IpArr, $Refid)
        {
                $this->SetTable('gymfacility');
                $this->AddFlds($IpArr);
                $this->SetWhere("refid = '{$Refid}'");
                $this->UpdQuery();
                return $Refid;
        }


        public function GetAllGymFacility()
        {
            $this->SetTable('gymfacility');
            $this->SetResultFlds("*");
            $this->SetWhere("stat != 'R'");
            $Res = $this->GetQuery();
            return $Res;
        }
        public function GetGymFacilityById($refid)
        {
            $this->SetTable('gymfacility');
            $this->SetResultFlds('*');
            $this->SetWhere("stat != 'R' AND  refid = '{$refid}' ");
            $Res = $this->GetQuery();
            return $Res;
        }
        public function IsExist($card_id, $refid)
        {
            $this->SetTable('gymfacility');
            $this->SetResultFlds('*');
            $this->SetWhere("gymfacilities = '{$card_id}' AND stat != 'R' AND refid !={$refid}");
            $res=$this->GetQuery();
            return count($res);
        }

    }
?>
```

csss

```
.title {
font-size: 20px;
color: #0C0;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #FFF;
font-size: 12px;
color: #424242;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 20px;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;


rowElem {
clear: both;
border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
padding: 10px 16px;
position: relative;
}

content {
padding-bottom: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
}
content {
padding-bottom: 80px;
overflow: hidden;
}


fieldset {
display: block;
-webkit-margin-start: 2px;
-webkit-margin-end: 2px;
-webkit-padding-before: 0.35em;
-webkit-padding-start: 0.75em;
-webkit-padding-end: 0.75em;
-webkit-padding-after: 0.625em;
border: 2px groove threedface;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
min-width: -webkit-min-content;
}

title {
font-size: 20px;
color: #0C0;
}

greyishBtn:hover {
background-position: 0 -25px;
}


button {
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 5px 14px 6px 14px;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height: 12px;
}
.submitForm {
float: right;
margin: 1px 27px 1px 16px;
}
.greyishBtn {
background: url(../images/ui/greyishBtn.png) repeat-x 0 0;
border: 1px solid #4f5a68;
color: #fff;
}
div {
display: block;
}
```